# How to sum and goup the same (parameters) records in one table MySQL

Tags: mysql, parameters, count, sum

Hi there just below my code:

```
DROP TABLE if exists project_has_tasks;

CREATE TABLE project_has_tasks (`project_id`int(6),`milestone_id` int(6), `status` varchar(100), `value` int(6));

INSERT INTO project_has_tasks (`project_id`, `milestone_id`, `status`, `value`) VALUES 
(56,1, 'undone', 56),
(56,1, 'done', 25),
(56,2, 'done', 25),
(56,3, 'done', 25),
(56,3, 'done', 25),
(56,4, 'undone', 25);


SELECT `milestone_id`, sum(value), 
CASE WHEN (status !='done') 
THEN (value ='0') ELSE sum(value) END as val 
FROM project_has_tasks WHERE project_id='56' 
AND milestone_id !=0 GROUP BY milestone_id ASC
```

Results:

```
 milestone_id | sum(value) | val
 1            | 81         | 0
 2            | 25         | 25
 3            | 50         | 50
 4            | 25         | 0
```

And everything looks seemingly ok but I would like to sum the records where task is done and undone either so the correct results should looks like this:

```
 milestone_id | sum(value) | val
 1            | 81         | 25
 2            | 25         | 25
 3            | 50         | 50
 4            | 25         | 0
```

So the milestone_id =1 should equal 25 'cause I have two of them in the table. One is undone(56), and the second is 25(done) so the result should be 25. Can you guys please help me in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just change a litte your CASE statement:

```
SELECT `milestone_id`, sum(value), 
SUM(CASE WHEN (status !='done') THEN 0 ELSE value END) as val 
FROM project_has_tasks WHERE project_id='56' 
AND milestone_id !=0 GROUP BY milestone_id ASC
```

Output:

```
    milestone_id    sum(value)  val
1   1   81  25
2   2   25  25
3   3   50  50
4   4   25  0
```

Comment: Works brilliant, thanks etsa, thanks stackoverflow.com :)